# How are modules loaded dynamically if there is only a single bundled JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I know when using a module loader like *webpack* the resulting output will be a single JavaScript file like `bundle.js`. Now in `index.html` I only need to reference the following:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

My question is, if I have a single `.js` file, how does dynamic module loading occur? Maybe I'm way off here in my understanding, but isn't the whole idea of a module loader to *not* server a module `.js` file until it is needed? Hence not having to load all files from the start of the app and `index.html`. Well if I have already served up that single `bundle.js` file from `index.html`, how are the separate modules within that file served up async and only as needed? At that point I feel I've already taken the hit for downloading the file, so the performance part is not gained.

How do the module loaders work when only a single bundled `.js` file is served for the entire app?

Comment: The bundle only includes files that are `required` or whatever (depends on the bundler), so you can have boatloads of modules in a project (or more likely, a framework that your project is being built in) and only the ones you explicitly use in your app are bundled in.

Comment: Webpack isn't a module loader, it's a module *bundler*. It's combining all the code into one file, as you said. That's very different and no dynamic loading is happening anywhere.

Comment: @Sami: Except when you do code splitting, which is very much encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Webpack this way you're not using any module loaders or dynamic loading. Webpack is a module *bundler* which means it resolves all the required modules, combines them into a single file and allows you to include that in your web page (or wherever you want to use the code).

If you were working in an environment where module loading was supported, you wouldn't even need Webpack (not going into minifying, transpiling or polyfilling here). You would just use module loading and that's it.

Comment: So is it recommended the to use Webpack with a module loader to have the best of both worlds? Or as you refer to "an environment where module loading was supported" do you mean a browser where `ES6 module loading` is supported or something else?

Comment: @atconway It depends on your requirements. Webpack with code splitting may be a good idea for many. And yes, I mean native ES6 support, which of course in the web will probably still benefit from bundling since it means less loading. But you don't need a module loader with Webpack in any case.

Answer (score 1):

As others recommended, what might interest you is webpack's code splitting.
I'm also a newcomer to webpack, but this is how I understand it.

`app.js`:

```
var $ = require('jquery'); // adds contents of jquery.js into the global bundle

// do stuff on runtime

module.exports = (function () {

    // do stuff above the fold (but only if app() is called)

    // time to use a module from outside of our bundle
    require.ensure([
        "./below_the_fold.js" // here you define which files will the new chunk contain (it is created on webpack compile)
    ], (require) => {
        // callback after the chunk is dynamically loaded by JSONP

        var moduleBelow = require("./below_the_fold.js"); // this particular require() which is inside require.ensure doesn't add required file into the bundle

        // do stuff below the fold (that needs moduleBelow which is what below_the_fold.js exports)

    }, 'below_the_fold'); // optional name of chunk file

});

window.app = module.exports
```

`below_the_fold.js`:

```
module.exports = (() => {
    // some logic we don't want into our global bundle because it's heavy or rarely used

    console.log('doing stuff below the fold is now possible');
})();
```